# Windows 7 Boot Failure after Unetbootin Installation of Ubuntu due to Partition Type

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, multi-boot, unetbootin

I successfully installed Ubuntu using unetbootin on my small Windows 7 PC. When I restart the computer I am given options to proceed with a Unetbootin boot or Windows 7 boot, as expected. The Unetbootin starts Ubuntu smoothly. Windows 7, however, will no longer boot.

Somehow in the process I accidentally modified the largest windows partition to a "linux swap" type.  I tried changing it to HPFS/NTFS, but I'm not sure this is right either and it doesn't work. This partition is currently labelled "Windows Partition 2 238 GB NTFS". My other partitions are

```
SYSTEM Partition 1 716 MB NTFS
HP_RECOVERY Partition 3 13_GB NTFS
HP_TOOLS Partition 4 2.1 GB FAT
```

I forgot what the default partition type was before I changed it to a "linux swap". Any insights?

Comment: Unetbootin is for creating the bootable USB's. The option there is not to boot from Windows, it's for booting from the first hard drive. If you remove the USB, you'll no longer see the Unetbootin menu, only the GRUB loader which you probably installed during Ubuntu setup. Apologies if I misunderstood.

Comment: @Russian Soyuz Rocket  No I do get the option regardless of whether the USB is inserted or not.  I had proceeded to install Ubuntu following the initial unetbootin program.